# MS Word field camp to distinguish between Good Morning, Good Afternoon,

Tags: if-statement, ms-word, field

I need a field to automate a Word Document for the greeting based on time (good morning, good afternoon)

In excel, i know that

```
=IF(HOUR(NOW())<=11;"Good Morning, ";IF(HOUR(NOW())>=18;"Good Evening, ";"Good Afternoon, "))
```

The above formula in excel gives me a greeting based on day time
How can i reflect that onto a Filed Code in MS Word? At least just Good Morning and Good Afternoon

I tried this way there in a field code

```
 { IF {TIME  \@ "am/pm"} = "am" "Good Morning,", "Good Afternoon" }
```

But doesn't seem to work

If anyone can tell me what is wrong in this code, or missing I'll be grateful.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

Good {=INT({TIME \@ hh}/6)-2 \# "'evening';'morning';'afternoon'"}

**Note**: Both sets of field brace pairs (i.e. '{ }') for the above example are created in the document itself, via Ctrl-F9 (Cmd-F9 on a Mac or, if you’re using a laptop, you might need to use Ctrl-Fn-F9); you can't simply type them or copy & paste them from this message. Nor is it practical to add them via any of the standard Word dialogues. The spaces represented in the field construction are all required.

Comment: Thanks a lot macropod, works perfectly!! I'm like newbie at field codes in MS Word and also here in Stackoverflow, sorry for any incovenience in my post. This one solution will save me a lot of time while composing e-mails and other stuff. Thanks a ton!! and a Happy new year for you :))

Comment: You might also be interested in my **Microsoft Word Date Calculation Tutorial**, available at:
https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38719-microsoft-word-date-calculation-tutorial.html and my **Microsoft Word Field Maths Tutorial**, available at:
https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38720-microsoft-word-field-maths-tutorial.html. Both are also available at: http://www.gmayor.com/downloads.htm#Third_party